# Can't insert date column from dataframe into date column in SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server, date, lubridate

I have a dataframe taken from a csv file which contains several columns with dates. The format of the dates are either `12/05/2019` or `2019-08-15T00:00:00Z` depending on the column.

I have cleaned up the columns using the following code:

```
transform(DataframeName,
     First_Date = dmy(First_Date)
     Second_Date = ymd_hms(Second_Date))
```

This successfully gets all of the dates into a `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

I am trying to import this dataframe into a SQL database using the following command:

```
dbWriteTable(con, "DatabaseTable", DataframeName, append = TRUE)
```

Whenever I do so I get the following error:

> Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values) :
>   nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 22018: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
>   Server]Invalid character value for cast specification

I have confirmed that the only columns causing this error are the date columns, and they're all causing it. I've tried converting the dates to strings, converting the strings back to a different date, using `as.Date`, importing numbers, converting empty values to `NA` and nothing has worked.  When I try and transform the column again (to try and make it a string literal) it reverts back to the original value. For example:

Original value: `12/05/2019`

```
transform(DataframeName,
     First_Date = dmy(First_Date)
```

Next value: `2019-05-12`

```
sqlData(con, DataframeName, row.names = NA
```

Last value: `12/05/2019`

As though it never actually transformed in the first place.

I've previously imported date columns from very similar csv files just using `as.Date` so I can't work out what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by not actually saving any of the transformations to the dataframe. If you see the above code it shows this:

```
transform(DataframeName,
    First_Date = dmy(First_Date)
```

When instead it should be *this*:

```
DataframeName <- transform(DataframeName,
    First_Date = dmy(First_Date)
```

The results of the transform being displayed in the console under the chunk that is being run can trick you here, even though it isn't overwriting anything. The comment about the value seeming to revert if it is transformed again is a big clue.

Don't forget to double check the simple things.